# Dividing the dataset in training and testing data with lables

Tags: python, r, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am trying to divide the dataset to training and testing set, in below code, `df_min_max_scaled` is my normalized data, `df` is my unnormalized data, but I am getting error

```
import numpy as np
train_ind = df.sample(frac=0.65, replace=True)
train = df_min_max_scaled[train_ind,]
test = df_min_max_scaled[-train_ind,]
train_labels = df[train_ind, 12] 
test_labels = df[-train_ind, 12]
#train_labels
```

Error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-a640d18b42fc> in <module>
      1 import numpy as np
      2 train_ind = df.sample(frac=0.65, replace=True)
----> 3 train = df_min_max_scaled[train_ind,]
      4 test = df_min_max_scaled[-train_ind,]
      5 train_labels = df[train_ind, 12]
```

Its showing error on line-3, I am actually converting R code to Python using Pandas

```
train_ind = sample(nrow(wine), floor(0.65 * nrow(wine)))
train = wine2[train_ind,]
test = wine2[-train_ind,]
train_labels = wine[train_ind, 12] 
test_labels = wine[-train_ind, 12]
```

Comment: That is not how you subset data in python.  which module/package are you using in python - pandas, vaex, spark etc? Seems you are an R person. You should either stick to R or simply learn python basics. For example you cannot write R code in C++ and expect the c++ code to run, you simply have to learn the syntax of that language.

Comment: I am using pandas, just struggling with this conversion.

Comment: `train_ind` in pandas is already the train dataset. Probably you need `train_ind = np.random.choice(wine.shape[0], np.floor(0.65 * wine.shape[0]))`

Comment: Then you could use that to subset

Comment: Thank you for the help then train and test remain the same ?

Comment: No test will be the compliment

Comment: Use train_test_split function if you need a quick fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to use `train_test_split` from sklearn. This could contain following steps:

1. Load your data (e.g. `df = pd.read_csv(...)` if your data comes from CSV files)
2. Split them using train test split (`from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split`), where `df` are your inputs and `labels` are true targets (you can set test_size to any value you want).

```
train, test, train_labels, test_labels = train_test_split(df, labels, test_size=0.35)
```

3. Apply your scaling (I recommend applying scaling after splitting so you can fit e.g. min-max scaler on train data, not both)

If you really insist on using sample function from pandas, you could do the following:

- get train data: `train = df.sample(frac=0.65)`
- get test data (rest of the 35% of data): `test = df.drop(train.index)`
- labels can be extracted by `train_labels = train.iloc[12]` (if I understand you correctly that `12` is the position of label in dataframe columns)
- and/or finally the right scaled data can be accessed via `df_min_max_scaled.loc[train.index]`

Just ensure you use the same index for both scaled/unscaled data.

Comment: In second case using sample with pandas what would be our `test_labels` because we can not create confusion matrix without it right ?

Comment: Yes, you are right. You should be able to get them from test data (`test`) similarly like train labels -> `test_labels = test.iloc[12]`. But note, that you should remove those labels from train data, since any model should not see those data during training.